# *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request

Tags: boot, nvidia, intel-graphics, intel

After swapping to the IGP in Nvidia X server settings (I believe it's called), my laptop no longer boots up. I get the following message when I try:

```
[    5.327876] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request.
```

Laptop specs:

- Intel i7 6700HQ
- Nvidia 1060GTX
- 240GB SSD (Sata3) Kingston
- 8GB of Kingston DDR4

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this error, if I try to boot several times in a row I don't even get to see that message. I only get:

```
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean, 279773/5464064 files, 3236827/21840640 blocks
```

It just locks up after that, every time I try to boot. I tried googling the problem in the hopes of finding a solution, but I couldn't find anything relevant. (Seemingly same errors, but with old between for and forcewake)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Albeit late, hopefully this helps others that come across this question.

You should be able to get past your error by adding the following kernel parameter `nouveau.modeset=0`.

In order to do so simply:

1. Upon seeing the GRUB screen hover over "Ubuntu" and press <kbd>e</kbd>.
2. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the line starting with `linux` (this line most likely has `splash` and `quiet` near the end, simply place it right after this).
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> and you should be in.

I know that this is a bit of a dirty workaround, but at least it allows you to get back in to your system. I will update this post if I find a cleaner alternative.