# Ubuntu 16.04 i915 drm kernel related error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel

I am using 4.14.1 kernel with Ubuntu 16.04 in a intel core M3 device. I am running my process which is using CPU/GPU time to time but the usage is not abnormal (100% CPU usage out of 400%)but after running for some hours, my system is getting hung with this 
**error: timed out waiting for forcewake ack request(It's not coming at boot time)**

I have checked the memory usage also it was normal, no memory leak.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The 4.14 kernel is not supported by Canonical or Ubuntu, so I'd recommend you using 16.04's 4.4 or 4.15 kernel choices instead.  With 4.14 all patches or security fixes are completely on you to perform, including re-compiling, review  and testing which is quite a job.  It's better to use supported kernels where all the work is performed for you (using 4.4 or 4.15 kernel choices).  Have you applied all fixes to 4.14?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can I use the latest available kernel 4.20 ? I have also check this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/973661/error-render-timed-out-waiting-for-forcewake-ack-request. Is setting nouveau.modeset=0 in the grub file help ?

Comment: 4.20 was a testing kernel only in Ubuntu (unsupported, compiled and used for testing purposes only), 4.18 was used by 18.10 which is now EOL & thus it's unsupported, as is 5.0 used by 19.04... (other kernels between 4.15, 4.18, 5.0 were testing only and of those only 4.15 gets security fixes back-ported to it due to EOL status of others).  `nouveau` is the open-source driver for nvidia, you mention intel's i915 in the heading so I don't see how it would help or how it relates sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using 4.15.0.76 kernel but still after running my process  continuously for some time I am getting the error : blitter timed out waiting for forcewake ack request and system is hanging afterwards. Do I have to change anything else?